# Why doesn't url-copy-file download these files?

Tags: url

I discovered [this issue](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/issues/134) while trying to install [all-the-icons](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el).

One step of installation involves using `url-copy-file` to install fonts. After running the install script, the font files are found in the correct place but are all empty. I verified that the script was not part of the problem by evaluating the `url-copy-file` expression myself with the proper values:

`(url-copy-file "https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/blob/master/fonts/all-the-icons.ttf?raw=true" "/home/me/.local/share/fonts/all-the-icons.ttf" t)`

A file was created in my local filesytem in the correct place, but it was empty. I tried wgetting the file manually from github, and the download was successful.

Why doesn't `url-copy-file` work on my system? I am using arch linux, but in the issue logged on `all-the-icons` github repo, I see that other users with this problem are using FreeBSD. I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Random guess: This URL leads to a redirect instead of a file, so if `url-copy-file` doesn't handle the redirect it won't download a file. You can test this by using `curl` as it doesn't automaticall follow redirects.